# Find and disable/filter DOM intelliSense recommendations in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a blank/new `.js` file. For some reason intelliSense/autocomplete is recommending things that I do not recognize nor do I know where they are coming from. Is there a way to either remove these recommendations entirely (I'll never need/use them) or some how filter/exclude them (either globally, per work-space, or by extension)?

This is what I see when I start typing `doit`:

[image]

If I select/add `DocumentTimeline` and then CTRL+click on `DocumentTimeline`, this is what I see:

[image]

I don't know how this got here? I don't recall installing anything. I don't want to [filter by type](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions) as there are valid recommendations I want in all the types.

Comment: Do you want to stop visual studio code from giving recommendations ?
If yes, then you could do so by adding the following in settings.json file

"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
}

Comment: No, I still want suggestions. I just don't want these ones.

Comment: Why would anyone close a question with an accepted answer. Seems odd and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this in your `jsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

      "lib": ["es6", "esnext"]  // or whatever in there, just not "dom"
      // intellisense will show you all the possible entries

   },
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
  ],
}
```

See [github issue: getting rid of DOM types](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20414).  I assume the `lib` option is "defining the context" of your project and without limiting it as in the example above you are getting much more "context" than you wish, you are getting the `dom` option.

And in general see [vscode docs on jsconfig](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig).

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to set a global `jsconfig.json` file? I can't find anything about where to put it.