# VSCode intellisense flooded with css classes in typescript

Tags: css, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've been having some annoyance with vscode while programming in typescript, intellisense seems to think that any object in a typescript file has all of the css classes as properties, when I type a "." after any object it shows a list including the objects methods, properties and a tuck load of css classes making intellisense virtually useless.

I've tried disabling all the extensions that I felt might have something related to it to no avail, but here is the list of extensions I have installed in case I missed something:

Beautify

DotENV

Heroku

heroku-cli

HTML CSS Support

HTML Preview

IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML

Material Icon Theme

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57916941/find-and-disable-filter-dom-intellisense-recommendations-in-vs-code/57917499#57917499 Just use tsconfig instead of jsconfig More info https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to disable these 2 plugins and check again:

HTML CSS Support

IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML

Comment: thanks, @sergio!
this was annoying me for moths

@thomas, I can confirm that this was happening because of `ecmel.vscode-html-css` extension

(found corresponding issue: https://github.com/ecmel/vscode-html-css/issues/138)