# VSCode intellisense is too sensitive

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

Often when I'm typing a function or variable, intellisense will pop up with entirely irrelevant suggestions simply because those suggestions contain the letters I've typed. Here I am typing the word "anon":

[image]

I [cannot find](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense) a solution in the intellisense settings, nor in any search-related setting; even the `CTRL+P` Command Palette does this, but cannot find some global sensitivity or threshold setting.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57916941/find-and-disable-filter-dom-intellisense-recommendations-in-vs-code/57917499#57917499 will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the lead, though I had come across it before; still I decided to implement it just now and it helps, but I'm still getting a ton of junk in there.